# Brakepoint в JS для слайдера

Tags: javascript, slider

Имеется слайдер из 3 блоков.
Пока ширина видимой области родительского блока составляет 280px все работает хорошо, поскольку перемещение основывается на изменении положения каждого блока слайдера отностительно родителя:

```
transform = "translateX(0px)"
transform = "translateX(-280px)"
transform = "translateX(-560px)"
```

Есть идея изменить ширину родительского блока через @media (min-width: 660px) {...}
Поскольку ширина блока родителя увеличится, то слайд не будет прокручиваться полностью.
Подскажите, как можно это реализовать в JavaScript?

Исходный код:

```js
var slideHandler = document.querySelector('.slider__toggles')

slideHandler.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var firstInput = slideHandler.querySelector('.slider__input--one');
  var secondInput = slideHandler.querySelector('.slider__input--two');
  var thirdInput = slideHandler.querySelector('.slider__input--three');
  var magicDiv = document.querySelector('.slider__items'); //что катается
  var magicDiv2 = document.querySelector('.slider');


  if (firstInput.checked) {
    magicDiv.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
  }
  if (secondInput.checked) {
    magicDiv.style.transform = "translateX(-280px)";
  }
  if (thirdInput.checked) {
    magicDiv.style.transform = "translateX(-560px)";
  }
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.slider__inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__items {
  display: flex;
  width: 300%;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

.slider__slide-title {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider__slide-comment {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.slider__toggles {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.slider__input {
  display: none;
}

.slider__toggle-label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-right: 13px;
}

.slider__toggle-label::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #BEC2C7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 12px;
  left: -3px;
}

.slider__input:checked+.slider__toggle-label::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #283645;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__items">
        <div class="slider__slide">
          <h2 class="slider__slide-title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
          <p class="slider__slide-comment">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae aspernatur amet, nobis at ipsa, vero dicta porro nisi officiis maiores soluta. Velit nostrum nisi saepe, architecto earum consequuntur quo incidunt!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__slide">
          <h2 class="slider__slide-title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
          <p class="slider__slide-comment">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae aspernatur amet, nobis at ipsa, vero dicta porro nisi officiis maiores soluta. Velit nostrum nisi saepe, architecto earum consequuntur quo incidunt!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__slide">
          <h2 class="slider__slide-title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
          <p class="slider__slide-comment">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae aspernatur amet, nobis at ipsa, vero dicta porro nisi officiis maiores soluta. Velit nostrum nisi saepe, architecto earum consequuntur quo incidunt!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__toggles">
      <input class="slider__input slider__input--one" type="radio" name="point" id="slide1" checked>
      <label class="slider__toggle-label" for="slide1"></label>
      <input class="slider__input slider__input--two" type="radio" name="point" id="slide2">
      <label class="slider__toggle-label" for="slide2"></label>
      <input class="slider__input slider__input--three" type="radio" name="point" id="slide3">
      <label class="slider__toggle-label" for="slide3"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если слайды имеют такую же ширину, как и ширина родительского блока, то можно обойтись и без `js`.

Можно использовать проценты, вместо пикселей.

```js
function changeSliderWidth(e) {
  d1.style.width = inputWidth.value + "px";
}
```

```css
#d1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#d1 .slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#d1 .slide1 {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#d1 .slide2 {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#d1 .slide3 {
  background-color: green;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <div class="slide slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide slide3"></div>
</div>
<label> Изменить ширину родителя
<input type="range" id="inputWidth" oninput="changeSliderWidth()" value="200" min="10" max="500">
</label>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Использовал % и все работает. Оказалось проще простого)